# Jena Query SPARQL using contains and lcase

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I am trying to get data from my RDF using query FILTER CONTAINS LCASE but it doesn't show anything. I am supposed to show *Komputasi dan Sistem Cerdas* here. This below is query i use:

```
SELECT ?x ?z 
WHERE { 
?x rdfs:label ?z  .
FILTER CONTAINS (LCASE (str(?z)), 'Komputasi') .
 }
```

So, i want to do here is if i search it using "komputasi" or "KOMPUTASI" or "kOmputasi" it doesn't matter for the user and it can return all values. But i need to use CONTAINS so it can return data with whitespace (i am using `rdfs:label` here).

What am i supposed to do?

Comment: ehm, but now you make all literals `?z` found in your data lower case but your search term is not lower case ... how do you think this could match then? "**K**omputasi" ...

Comment: it should be obvious to do `FILTER CONTAINS (LCASE (str(?z)), LCASE('YOUR_SEARCH_TERM_HERE')) .` - if you really are to lazy to make the search term lower case in your client code before putting it into the query

Comment: it solved. i put `LCASE` both in str and 'Komputasi'.

Comment: ... well, that's what I showed you or not?

Comment: Yess! Thanks for the helps!